# How to convert spherical co-ordinates of a vector field to cartesian co-ordinates :

Tags: multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem

**v**$(r,φ,θ) = (r cos2  θ)$**r**$ − (rcosθsinθ)$**θ**$ + 3r$**φ**, where **r**, **θ** and **φ** are the unit spherical vectors.

I was trying to calculate the line integral of the function along the path described in the picture below, but I need the function in cartesian coordinates to do so right? If I do, how do we do that? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simpler to work this out in spherical coordinates. I assume that $\theta$ is the polar angle. You can verify that
$$\nabla \times \mathbf v =
(3 \cot \theta) \boldsymbol r - 6 \boldsymbol \theta +
 (\sin 2 \theta) \boldsymbol \phi, \\
(0, 0, 1) \big\rvert_{\theta = \pi/2} = -\boldsymbol \theta, \\
(1, 0, 0) \big\rvert_{\phi = \pi/2} = -\boldsymbol \phi,$$
therefore you need to evaluate $\iint 6 \, dS$ over the shaded quarter-disk and $-\iint \sin 2 \theta \, dS$ over the shaded triangle, the latter giving
$$-\int_{\arctan(1/2)}^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\csc \theta}
 r \sin 2 \theta \, dr d\theta =
-\int_{\arctan(1/2)}^{\pi/2} \cot \theta \, d\theta =
-\ln \sin \theta \bigg\rvert_{\theta = \arctan(1/2)}^{\pi/2}.$$